# Add column to 2d array mapped from a flat associative lookup array

Tags: php, arrays, mapping, lookup, array-map

I have an associative array of counts with `brand_slug` keys and a 2d array to which I would like to append related count data.

```
$countArray = [
    "abu-garcia" => 1,
    "daiwa" => 4,
    "shimano" => 4
];

$dataArray = [
    [
        "brand_id" => 36,
        "brand_name" => "Abu Garcia",
        "brand_slug" => "abu-garcia"
    ],
    [
        "brand_id" => 41,
        "brand_name" => "Daiwa",
        "brand_slug" => "daiwa"
    ],
    [
        "brand_id" => 41,
        "brand_name" => "Daiwa",
        "brand_slug" => "daiwa"
    ],
    [
        "brand_id" => 39,
        "brand_name" => "Shimano",
        "brand_slug" => "shimano"
    ],
    [
        "brand_id" => 39,
        "brand_name" => "Shimano",
        "brand_slug" => "shimano"
    ],
];
```

I want to create a new array which should look like this:

```
[
    [
        "brand_id" => 36,
        "brand_name" => "Abu Garcia",
        "brand_slug" => "abu-garcia",
        "count" => 1
    ],
    [
        "brand_id" => 41,
        "brand_name" => "Daiwa",
        "brand_slug" => "daiwa",
        "count" => 4,
    ],
    [
        "brand_id" => 41,
        "brand_name" => "Daiwa",
        "brand_slug" => "daiwa",
        "count" => 4
    ],
    [
        "brand_id" => 39,
        "brand_name" => "Shimano",
        "brand_slug" => "shimano",
        "count" => 4
    ],
    [
        "brand_id" => 39,
        "brand_name" => "Shimano",
        "brand_slug" => "shimano",
        "count" => 4
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do...

If these are examples of your arrays:

```
$CountArray = array("abu-garcia"=>1,
                "daiwa"=>4,
                "shimano"=>4);
$DataArray = array(
            array("brand_id"=>36, "brand_name"=>"Abu Garcia", "brand_slug"=>"abu-garcia"),
            array("brand_id"=>41, "brand_name"=>"Daiwa", "brand_slug"=>"daiwa"),
            array("brand_id"=>39, "brand_name"=>"Shimano", "brand_slug"=>"shimano")
);
```

Then loop through your second array to build a new array, and adding the `count` key from the first array like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($DataArray as $ItemArray){
    foreach($ItemArray as $Key=>$Value){
        $NewArray[$i][$Key] = $Value;
        $NewArray[$i]['count'] = 0;
        if(isset($CountArray[$ItemArray['brand_slug']])){
            $NewArray[$i]['count'] = $CountArray[$ItemArray['brand_slug']];         
        }
    }
    ksort($NewArray[$i]);
    $i++;
}
print_r($NewArray);
```

Comment: In no way do I endorse using a nested loop or iterated calls of `ksort()` for this task.

Answer (score 0):

In a simplest way you can do like this.
Suppose your first array name is $first_array  and second one is $second_array.

just loop the second one like

```
foreach($second_array as $index => $item)
{
    $second_array[$index]['count'] = $first_array[$item['brand_slug']];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($second_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The task of adding a new column to all rows in a 2d array based on an associative lookup/mapping array is most elegantly done with `array_map()` and the array union operator (`+`).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pilbe))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => $row + ['count' => $countArray[$row['brand_slug']]],
        $dataArray
    )
);
```

There is also nothing wrong with modifying the data array by reference in a classic `foreach()` loop . ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IsWLB))

```
foreach ($dataArray as &$row) {
    $row['count'] = $countArray[$row['brand_slug']];
}
var_export($dataArray);
```

---

As a consideration not presented in the asker's sample data, if a row's value is not found in the mapping array, use the null coalescing operator to fallback to a default value.

```
['count' => $countArray[$row['brand_slug']] ?? $someDefault]
```

Or

```
$row['count'] = $countArray[$row['brand_slug']] ?? $someDefault;
```

Answer (score -1):

**array_merge**
Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

> Example #array_merge() example

```
<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the asked question.